# Re-order entire page with CSS flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to change the order of my entire page for mobile devices, using Flex. I can get this working inside the individual container, but is it possible to do it with all containers on the page? Here is an example:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#a {
  order: 4;
  background: #ccc;
}
#b {
  order: 1;
  background: #aaa;
}
#c {
  order: 3;
  background: #d33;
}
.one {
  order: 2;
  background: #aaa;
}
.two {
  order: 5;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
  </div>
  <div id="flex2">
    <div class="one">Show me 2nd</div>
    <div class="two">Show me 5th</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 'Show me 2nd' and 'Show me 5th' just sit at the end rather than in the new order. To confirm, the HTML can't be changed.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chotd9sv/)

Comment: display:contents would help if avalaible elsewhere than firefox http://jsfiddle.net/chotd9sv/3/ as it is , you need javascript to rebuild  the dom  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display look at display:box for an explanation or https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box-generation

Comment: Thanks. This is for mobile devices only. So could display:contents work for that?

Comment: you need to run some test on different mobile/browsers , but i'm afraid it won't work yet

Comment: How would I do it with Javascript DOM? I have updated my JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chotd9sv/4/

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer?, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply an order with flex on elements that don't share the same container:

> The 'order' property controls the order in which flex items appear within their flex container, by assigning them to ordinal groups.

[Soucre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Advanced_layouts_with_flexbox#Flexbox_Order)

You can change your HTML structure, so all the elements will share the same container, and then the order rule will work.

Comment: "To confirm, the HTML can't be changed."

Answer (score 0):

via jquery you can use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) untill `display:contents` comes to the standards.

Actually [usable in Firefox](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mozilla.dev.platform/G2BkcDWptHQ/hlmh8bfWaq8J) for testing purpose [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/chotd9sv/3/).

```js
$('#flex2 > div, #flex  > div').clone().insertAfter('#flex2');
$('#flex2 , #flex').remove();
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#a {
  order: 4;
  background: #ccc;
}
#b {
  order: 1;
  background: #aaa;
}
#c {
  order: 3;
  background: #d33;
}
.one {
  order: 2;
  background: #aaa;
}
.two {
  order: 5;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
  </div>

  <div id="flex2">
    <div class="one">Show me 2nd</div>
    <div class="two">Show me 5th</div>
  </div>

</div>
```